# Need to make a custom View 4 times bigger than the screen

Tags: android, android-view

I want to set my custom `View` size to be *4 bigger than the screen so I can use accelerometer to move some object around that `View` which is in the background.

Background.java

```
package com.theeye.game;

private Paint backgroundSquarePaint = new Paint();
private Paint eraser = new Paint();
private Paint paintBorder = new Paint();
private Rect backgroundSquare = new Rect();
private Rect square = new Rect();
private int scale, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight, min, randomX, randomY, randomAngle;
private DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
private Random rW = new Random();
private Random rH = new Random();
private Random rA = new Random();
private View view = findViewById(R.id.background);

public Backgroind(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null, 0);
}

public Backgroind(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs, 0);
}

public Backgroind(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttyr) {

    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    scale = metrics.densityDpi / 160;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    maxWidth = width - 200 * scale;
    maxHeight = height - 200 * scale;
    min = 200 * scale;
    randomX = rW.nextInt((maxWidth - min) + 1) + min;
    randomY = rH.nextInt((maxHeight - min) + 1) + min;
    randomAngle = rA.nextInt((359 - 0) + 1) + 0;

    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintBorder.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    paintBorder.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintBorder.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paintBorder.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paintBorder.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    eraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    backgroundSquare.set(0, 0, width * 4, height * 4);
    backgroundSquarePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#162BA1"));
    square.set(0 - 110, 0 - 110, 0 + 110, 0 + 110);


    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scale.setDuration(10000);
    scale.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(scale);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(backgroundSquare, backgroundSquarePaint);
    canvas.translate(randomX, randomY);
    canvas.rotate(randomAngle);
    canvas.drawRect(square, eraser);
    canvas.drawRect(square, paintBorder);
    canvas.restore();

}

}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.theeye.game

private DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
private int height, width;
private SensorManager senSensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer;
private long lastUpdate = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
    width = metrics.widthPixels;

    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rect"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<com.theeye.game.Backgroind
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.theeye.game.Shapes
    android:id="@+id/shapes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I wanted to set the width and height of the custom view Background to 4 times that of the android mobile screen and i did it know by using onMesure.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

  setMeasuredDimension(width * 4, height * 4);

 }

Comment: but know i also want to move the background using the accelerometer from MainActivity ???